# Home Weather Station

Tags: solar-power

I am looking for a home weather station that can work as follows:

- **Cordless**: gets its power from battery + integrated solar panel
- **Wireless communication interface**: for retrieving and storing historical data from a computer/server. If power provided by battery or solar panel I'm assuming this won't be WIFI since it's too energy intensive, so maybe Bluetooth?

The idea is to install it on my roof to measure wind speed and sun exposure for a year in order to calculate potential Return On Investment if I were to install a wind turbine or solar panels.

I looked on Amazon and there are zillions out there, any recommendations to help me get started would be great.

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: 200 EUR / 220 USD